# Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members - Using Moltin API

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, moltin

I'm doing a tutorial from 2015 and very new to swift, I'm getting the Type `[AnyHashable : Any]?` has no subscript members error from the `self.objects` line.

```
Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: nil, success: { (responseDictionary)-> Void in
      //Assign Products array to object property
      self.objects = responseDictionary["result"] as! [AnyObject]

  }) { (responseDictionary, error) in
      print("Something went wrong!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to unwrap value for responseDictionary["result"]...
self.objects = responseDictionary["result"]! as! [AnyObject]

Comment: self.objects = responseDictionary?["result"] as! [AnyObject] this got rid of the error but the code still doesn't work properly even though the rest of the code to display the products is all correct. unwrapping didn't work either

Comment: Add a ! at the end of responseDictionary?["result"] to make it responseDictionary?["result"]!

Comment: Still didn't work :(

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Also, before that line could you run print(responseDictionary) and share the console log.

Comment: 2017-10-16 20:59:49.440862-0400 BHCStore[97427:7266470] com.moltin.sdk: GET: https://api.molt.in/v1/products
Optional([AnyHashable("pagination"): {
    current = 0;
    from = 0;
    limit = 10;
    links =     {
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
        next = 0;
        previous = 0;
    };
    offset = 0;
    offsets =     {
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
        next = 0;
        previous = 0;
    };
    to = 0;
    total = 0;
}, AnyHashable("status"): 1, AnyHashable("result"): <__NSArray0 0x60400001eca0>(

)
])

Comment: With your suggestions the error went away yet still not retrieving response correctly

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: This-----> Optional([AnyHashable("pagination"): {
    current = 0;
    from = 0;
    limit = 10;
    links =     {
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
        next = 0;
        previous = 0;
    };
    offset = 0;
    offsets =     {
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
        next = 0;
        previous = 0;
    };
    to = 0;
    total = 0;
}, AnyHashable("status"): 1, AnyHashable("result"): <__NSArray0 0x600000012e00>(

)

Comment: I meant the responseDictionary. Run this, print(responseDictionary["result"]!)

Comment: Give me the same ype '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members error when I type that line

Comment: That's strange. Can you share your project?

Comment: what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Zip it, add to Google Drive and share the link, or put it up on Github.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5potzbJ__DASkRhUXMxNFBJeEE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Refactored your code to properly cast the response into a dictionary.

```swift
Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: nil, success: { (response) -> Void in
    //Assign Products array to object property

    guard let responseDictionary = response as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        return
    }

    self.objects = responseDictionary["result"] as! [AnyObject]
    print(self.objects)
    //Tell the table view to reload it's data
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}) { (responseDictionary, error) in
    print("Something went wrong!")
}
```

I tried running your code after this, it works alright. The API isn't returning what you expect. Let's take a look...

```swift
let pagination = responseDictionary["pagination"]!
let results = responseDictionary["result"] as! [AnyObject]

print(pagination.count) // 8
print(results.count) // 0
```

As you can see there are 8 value under the `pagination` key but 0 under the `results` key. Which means that the parsing logic is correct. If there is an error it's on the API end.
The API doesn't return any results, that's why the table is empty.

Hard luck, I hope this helps though!

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I will just have to figure out what exactly is wrong on the API end. Good to know my code was alright though

Comment: Good luck with that.
At least we managed to fix the '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members error.